# Drawable to bitmap efficiently using Picasso onBitmapFailed() method

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I'm using target as callback mechanism (with Picasso).

```
private Target target = new Target() {  
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        // loading of the bitmap was a success
        // TODO do some action with the bitmap
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        // loading of the bitmap failed
        // TODO do some action/warning/error message
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
};

Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(...)
    .into(target);
```

I want to load placeholder if bitmap fails to load, here:

```
@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

}
```

My drawable placeholder is located locally in res/drawable folder.
Which is the best way to do the convertion from DRAWABLE to BITMAP?

**FIRST WAY**, (Alot of people suggests on SO this way):

```
Bitmap placeholderIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.placeholder);
```

**SECOND WAY**, (I think it should be more memory effiecient)

```
@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    errorDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.poster_placeholder);
    Bitmap placeholderIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) errorDrawable).getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: the "FIRST WAY" is a direct way - `getDrawable` uses `decodeResource` under the hood

Comment: @pskink But what about "BitmapFactory"? Isn't it heavy?

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java, it uses methods like [those](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#718)